# What are Scala standard exceptions?

Tags: exception, scala, notimplementedexception

What are the common standard exceptions in Scala?
I am especially interested in how is .Net's `NotImplementedException` equivalent called?

UPDATE: The answer about the `NotImplementedException` seems to be
[org.apache.commons.lang.NotImplementedException](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/NotImplementedException.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Almost nothing:

```
package scala {
  final class MatchError(obj: Any) extends RuntimeException
  final class UninitializedError extends RuntimeException("uninitialized value")
  final case class UninitializedFieldError (msg: String) extends RuntimeException(msg)

  package util.regex {
    class SyntaxError(e: String) extends RuntimeException(e)
  }

  package xml {

    class BrokenException() extends java.lang.Exception
    case class MalformedAttributeException(msg: String) extends RuntimeException(msg)

    package dtd {
      case class ValidationException(e: String) extends Exception(e)
    }

    package include {
      class CircularIncludeException(message: String) extends XIncludeException
      class UnavailableResourceException(message: String) extends XIncludeException(message)
      class XIncludeException(message: String) extends Exception(message)
    }

    package parsing {
      case class FatalError(msg: String) extends java.lang.RuntimeException(msg)
    }
  }
}
```

The rest comes from Java, which cover pretty much all corners. It begs the question of what these Scala methods throw on other platforms, doesn't it?

Comment: That gives a pretty fair idea of just how easy it is to throw your own custom Exceptions and even errors if it works with Java. Just make a one line class in an object and use as needed. final class MyException(arg:String) extends RuntimeException() or as seen in FatalError with java.lang.RuntimeException(msg). Nice one Sobral.

Answer (score 2):

The `NotImplementedException` is currently being considered for Scala 2.10, probably. See this [thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/11113).

Comment: `UnsupportedOperationException` of course isn't being considered for Scala 2.10. It has been part of the Java library for a long time. The thread is about adding a conveniece method that throws it to Predef.

Comment: First of all, UnsupportedOperationException and NotImplementedException mean totally different things and both are needed (I used to use both of them actively in C# projects of mine). And the question is what to use today, in Scala 2.9.1? I use to define a class and then implement it method-by-method, using "throw new NotImplementedException()" as not yet implemented methods bodies and compiling the project many times before I implement everything. But in Scala it seems like I have to implement all the functions by returning some dummy data - this may cause bugs and is just annoying.

Comment: As of 2.10, `???` has been added to `Predef`. You can now write code like `class Thing { def getThing = ??? }`. Calling `getThing` will raise `scala.NotImplementedError` with the message "an implementation is missing".

Answer (score 2):

You can just use whatever default already exists in Java. Scala doesn't really add anything to the standard exceptions in Java.